# Inserting multiple rows into database table using laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel

I am new to laravel 4 so, please tolerate me. I want to store the data I get from `create.blade.php` file into `store()` method of the controller. But I have become clueless at the controller part.

Here is my `create.blade.php` file

```
<p>
    <strong>Select No of Activites You Want To Fill Up:</strong>&nbsp;{{ Form:: select('noAct',array('1'=>1,'2'=>2,'3'=>3,'4'=>4,'5'=>5),'1',array('id'=>'noAct')); }}</strong>
</p>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>SN</th>
        <th>Activity Description</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Weightage</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>100</th>
        <th>75</th>
        <th>50</th>
        <th><50</th>
    </tr>
    <!--form to insert the user data-->
    {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'it')) }}

    <tbody id="tbodyappend"></tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" style="text-align:center;">{{ Form::submit('Add Activity',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function displayTable() {
            var noAct = $("#noAct").val();

            $("#tbodyappend").empty();
            //for loop to display the no of tables required
            for (var i = 0; i < noAct; i++) {
                //display the table
                $("#tbodyappend").append("<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input type='text' name='activity_name[]' required /></td><td><input type='text' name='activity_unit[]' required style='width:40px;' /></td><td><input type='text' name='activity_weight[]' required style='width:40px;' /></td><td><input type='text' name='activity_date[]' required style='width:40px;' /></td><td><input type='text' name='performance1[]' required style='width:40px;' /></td><td><input type='text' name='performance2[]' style='width:40px;' /></td> <td><input type='text' name='performance3[]' style='width:40px;' /></td><td><input type='text' name='performance4[]' style='width:40px;' /></td></tr>");

            }
        }


        $("select").change(displayTable);

    }); 
</script>
```

So, now I want to send data to my controller and insert into table. So, any assistance could be of great help to me.

You can see similar table of what I wanted to make here at:http://jsfiddle.net/xn2GP/1/

And you can see my paste: http://laravel.io/bin/RWXK

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT (actual answer): Avoid nesting a `<form>` inside a `<table>`, because it renders no `<input>` inside the `<form>`, thus sending no data**

You need to keep the inputs inside the form. Let's say I wanna store a blog post, and I'll need a title and the body:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'posts')) }}
    {{ Form::text('title') }}
    {{ Form::text('body') }}

    {{ Form::submit('Send') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then, I can access the values using `Input::get` and insert them into the `posts` table like this:

```
class PostsController extends \BaseController {

    public store()
    {
        // perform validation if needed

        $new_post = Post::create(array(
            'title' => Input::get('title'),
            'body' => Input::get('body')
        ));
    }
}
```

or

```
class PostsController extends \BaseController {

    public store()
    {
        // perform validation if needed

        $new_post        = new Post;
        $new_post->title = Input::get('title');
        $new_post->body  = Input::get('body');

        $new_post->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't we append a input field using jquery?

Comment: You can see similar part of what I wanted to make here:http://jsfiddle.net/xn2GP/1/                                           You can check my paste at http://laravel.io/bin/RWXK

Comment: your controller is asking for `Input::get('activity_name')` but your Javascript is appending `activity_name[]`

Comment: mm, there's something wrong with the form code, because if you open developer tools, you won't find any input inside the `<form>`, so the form isn't sending anything

Comment: I tried with Input::all();  But still I couldnot get any form data!!

Comment: check my last comment

Comment: Can you suggest me any ideas please?

Comment: sure, avoid using tables